# Advanced Custom Fields displaying on tag pages

Tags: plugins, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have edited Advanced Custom Fields before but never set anything up from scratch, always relied on developers. But I'm wanting to do a very specific thing and I was hoping I could do it by myself.

I just wanted to add a few fields in the usual Wordpress tags taxonomy, then have them appear on the frontend. I basically want to add related tags (I'm calling topics) on the tags page. So a field that I can input other tags and have them click to send them to those. I may add a couple other basic text fields, but I just want to get the fields to appear on the page.  I'm using a theme that may have a ton of things that are confusing what normally is seen, so if it helps to copy and paste a chunk of code from it, I can.

I have so far created the Field Group "tag_details" and the Field "related_topics". I have the field appearing on the backend of Wordpress correctly, when creating/editing tags. But I can't get it to appear on the front end.

I've tried different things from directions found here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

and:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/

I've tried inputting code in various places in tags.php. But nothing ever happens. I don't know if I have to put it in a very specific place, or it should be part of the other code on the page so it won't work just copy and pasting what is being suggested on those pages. Obviously I'm replacing things with the correct field group and field. But nothing is appearing.

Again, my knowledge is limited. But I was hoping this very specific use of ACF would be something I could pull off. Just about everything else I'm doing came already with the premium theme I purchased. Thanks for any help, and I can provide more info if needed.

Code below.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Category archive pages
 *
 */
 ?>
<?php
    get_header();
    $tagID          = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

    $archiveLayout  = tnm_archive::bk_get_archive_option($tagID, 'bk_archive_content_layout');
    $pagination     = tnm_archive::bk_get_archive_option($tagID, 'bk_archive_pagination');
    $sidebar        = tnm_archive::bk_get_archive_option($tagID, 'bk_archive_sidebar_select');
    $sidebarPos     = tnm_archive::bk_get_archive_option($tagID, 'bk_archive_sidebar_position');
    $sidebarSticky  = tnm_archive::bk_get_archive_option($tagID, 'bk_archive_sidebar_sticky'); 
    
    $moduleID = uniqid('tnm_posts_'.$archiveLayout.'-');
    $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
    $customArgs = array(
        'tag_id'            => $tagID,
        'post_type'         => array( 'post' ),
        'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'offset'            => 0,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
    );
    tnm_core::bk_add_buff('query', $moduleID, 'args', $customArgs);

?>
<div class="site-content">   
    
    <?php echo tnm_archive::tnm_archive_header($tagID);?>
            <?php if( ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list')       || 
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_a') || 
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_b') ||
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_c') || 
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid')       ||
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_alt_a') ||
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_alt_b') ||
                      ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_small')
                    ) {?>
    <div class="mnmd-block mnmd-block--fullwidth">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="mnmd-main-col <?php if($sidebarPos == 'left') echo('has-left-sidebar');?>" role="main">
                    <div id="<?php echo esc_attr($moduleID);?>" class="mnmd-block">
                        <?php 
                        if($pagination == 'ajax-loadmore') {
                            echo '<div class="js-ajax-load-post">';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php echo tnm_archive::archive_main_col($archiveLayout, $moduleID, $pagination);?>
                        <?php echo tnm_archive::bk_pagination_render($pagination);?>
                        <?php 
                        if($pagination == 'ajax-loadmore') {
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
        
                    <!-- .mnmd-block -->
                </div><!-- .mnmd-main-col -->

                <div class="mnmd-sub-col mnmd-sub-col--right sidebar <?php if($sidebarSticky != 0) echo 'js-sticky-sidebar';?>" role="complementary">
                    <div class="theiaStickySidebar">
                        <?php 
                            dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- .mnmd-sub-col -->
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- .mnmd-block -->
    <?php } elseif( 
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_no_sidebar')         ||
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_small_no_sidebar')   ||
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_no_sidebar')         ||
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_a_no_sidebar')   ||
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_b_no_sidebar')   ||
              ($archiveLayout == 'listing_list_alt_c_no_sidebar')
            ) {?>
    <div id="<?php echo esc_attr($moduleID);?>" class="mnmd-block mnmd-block--fullwidth">
        <?php
        if( ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_no_sidebar') || ($archiveLayout == 'listing_grid_small_no_sidebar') ) {
            echo '<div class="container">';
        }else {
            echo '<div class="container container--narrow">';
        }
        if($pagination == 'ajax-loadmore') {
            echo '<div class="js-ajax-load-post">';
        }
        
        echo tnm_archive::archive_fullwidth($archiveLayout, $moduleID, $pagination);
        echo tnm_archive::bk_pagination_render($pagination);
        
        if($pagination == 'ajax-loadmore') {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div><!-- .container -->';
        ?>
    </div><!-- .mnmd-block -->
    <?php }?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you share the piece of code in which you are fetching the term acf field value. Any error are you facing or nothin show up.

Comment: @Veerji   Thanks. I just added the code to the question. The entire tag.php file. I've tried adding stuff to various places and nothing really happens. At one point I saw a line break or something where I could at least tell for sure I'm editing the correct location. But no fields ever appeared.

Comment: have you try this : `$term_object = get_queried_object(); $acf_value = get_field('my_acf_name', $term_object); ` ? Add this below `get_header();` and simply echo the $acf_value.

Comment: @Veerji   I don't know what you mean by "echo the $acf_value" ... I vaguely see what you're talking about, but I don't know how to write code so I don't know what to put below (and where) in order to do that.